# Update Error in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Im getting a Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
This is an update button Im trying to implement.
Access_Num is the only number(data_type) here.
I'm using MSACCESS2007
Is it a good pracrice to make all data types in the database as text?

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
cn = New OleDbConnection(con)
    cn.Open()
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = "Update [Book] SET [Book_ID] = '" & TextBox1.Text & _
            "', [Access_Num] = '" &Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text) & _
            "', [Title] = '" & TextBox3.Text & _
            "', [Author] = '" & TextBox4.Text & _
            "', [Publisher] = '" & TextBox5.Text & _
            "', [Category] = '" & ComboBox1.Text & _
            "', [Contents] = '" & TextBox7.Text & _
            "', [Availability] = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "' WHERE [Access_Num] = '" & Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)  & "'"
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'cn.Close()
    'cmd.Dispose()

    MsgBox("Successfully Updated")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have string delimiters everywhere. Remove them for all fields that aren't strings:

```
With cmd
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "Update [Book] SET [Book_ID] = '" & TextBox1.Text & _
        "', [Access_Num] = " & Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text) & _
        ", [Title] = '" & TextBox3.Text & _
        "', [Author] = '" & TextBox4.Text & _
        "', [Publisher] = '" & TextBox5.Text & _
        "', [Category] = '" & ComboBox1.Text & _
        "', [Contents] = '" & TextBox7.Text & _
        "', [Availability] = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "' WHERE [Access_Num] = " & Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text) 
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Note that a better way would be to use parameters for the query, since that also avoids SQL injection.

> Is it a good pracrice to make all data types in the database as text?

No, certainly not! That's an awful practice. Data types should represent the data stored in the column, and be the smallest practical type to represent that data.

Comment: Thanks it's working now, but the my field Access_Num isn't updating at all,  all Text data types are updating except for the integer

Comment: Eh, that's logical, since you're specifying that field in the `WHERE`  condition. So you're updating Access_Num to 3, for example, only where it's already 3. If you have a different field identifying the records (for example, an autonumber field), you could use that in the `WHERE` condition, and then you could change it.

Comment: You mean I can't update the data that I'm referring to in my WHERE clause.  My Access_Num is the only unique key in my table. Is it fine to add an auto-number field just for updating purposes? Suppose to be an ID?

Comment: Yes, of course. Autonumbers are often used for exactly that purpose